# Специфика работы defer

Tags: golang

Почему в данной ситуации сначала выводится "Second" и "Third" (хотя они должны идти после "First"), а "Fourth" как раз лишь только после "First"? Хотя насколько мне известно, defer должен срабатывать перед закрытием функции, в которой он объявлен.
Я понимаю, что это связано с моей некомпетентностью, объясните пожалуйста.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    defer fmt.Println(changePointer())
    fmt.Println("First")
}

func changePointer() string {
    defer fmt.Println("Third")
    fmt.Println("Second")
    return "Fourth"
}
```

Comment: Аргументы для defer-функции вычисляются сразу же в той строке, в которой написан defer, и это приводит к тому, что `changePointer()` вызывается сразу в самом начале https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42703707

Comment: @andreymal Благодарю Вас!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`changePointer()` вызывается, потому что это необходимо для получения результата, который может быть использован в `fmt.Println(changePointer())`. Функция `changePointer` выполняется, чтобы получить результат, который возвращается в `main`, и только после этого запланированные `defer`-вызовы выполняются.

Comment: Да, но fmt.Println(changePointer()) также находится в defer. Почему оно все не выполнится в конце?

Comment: потому что, только анонимная функция не исполняется сразу. замените на  `defer func() {
  fmt.Println(changePointer())
 }()`, тогда не будет вычисляться сразу